# CKEditor only remove style attributes from pasted text

Tags: ckeditor, copy-paste, google-docs

This question seems to have a lot of questions with people that want the same thing, but none of the answers seem to address it correctly (here, or on the CKEditor forum), but how do I get pasted content to not get pasted with the style attributes?

My goal is *almost* pasting as plain text, but it removes tags like tables or bold tags (and yes I want the `em`, `strong`, `b`, etc.) to stay, I *only* don't want the style attributes.

I've used the formatting pasting plugin but that does a whole mess of things that isn't what I want, and the remove formatting button also removes all my tags that I want to keep.

Comment: Have you read [this one](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/HELP-paste-HTML-remove-STYLE)?

Comment: @wordbug I have, that was one of the CKEditor forum questions I was referring to, the answer essentially functions the same as always forcing the the paste to always be plain text, which is not what I'm after

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the CTRL+SHIFT+V shortcut ?

Comment: `My goal is *almost* pasting as plain text` - This is literally what I do not want to do

Answer (score 1):

One way we've accomplished this is by adding a `paste` event listener and updating the data:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
    event.editor.on('paste', function (ev) {
        let temp = document.createElement('div');

        temp.innerHTML = ev.data.dataValue;

        // get all child tags, regardless of depth
        // if you only want to remove the style attribute, can use [style] instead of *
        let allChildTags = temp.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for (let i = 0; i < allChildTags.length; i++) {
            let item = allChildTags.item(i);
            item.removeAttribute('style');
            // any other changes to these elements can be done here
        }

        // update the pasted value with the cleaned up HTML
        ev.data.dataValue = temp.innerHTML;

        temp.remove();
    });
});
```